# Bilinear interpolation function too slow - Javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an electron app where I receive some data from a camera via the serial port and then I display it using a canvas.

I want to use bilinear interpolation as the data received is only 64 pixels. The problem that I have is that the interpolation function is too slow and it cannot keep it with the data that is received via serial therefore it laggs and is not real time anymore.

Any idea what I can do to make it faster? 
Here is the function:

```
let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
let data = imgData.data;
for i {
  for j {
    //The size of a block is 64 pixels
    let indexX = Math.floor(j / (64 * 4));
    let indexY = Math.floor(i / 64);

    let Q11 = {
      x: index_X * 64,
      y: index_Y * 64,
      value: parseFloat(PixelData[indexX + indexY * 16])
    };

    let Q12 = {
      x: index_X * 64,
      y: (index_Y + 1) * 64,
      value: parseFloat(PixelData[indexX + (indexY + 1) * 16])
    };

    let Q21 = {
      x: (index_X + 1) * 64,
      y: index_Y * 64,
      value: parseFloat(PixelData[(indexX + 1) + indexY * 16])
    };

    let Q22 = {
      x: (index_X + 1) * 64,
      y: (index_Y + 1) * 64,
      value: parseFloat(PixelData[(indexX + 1) + (indexY + 1) * 16])
    };

    let R1 = Q11.value * ((Q21.x - (j / 4)) / 64) + Q21.value * (((j / 4) - Q11.x) / 64);
    let R2 = Q12.value * ((Q22.x - (j / 4)) / 64) + Q22.value * (((j / 4) - Q12.x) / 64);
    let MLXTempInterpolated = R1 * ((Q12.y - i) / 64) + R2 * ((i - Q21.y) / 64);
    let tempIndex = TempMap(MLXTempInterpolated, minTemp, maxTemp, 120) //This is pretty fast
    try {

      data[j + i * ((64 * 15 + 1) * 4) + 0] = colorPalette[tempIndex].r //r
      data[j + i * ((64 * 15 + 1) * 4) + 1] = colorPalette[tempIndex].g //g
      data[j + i * ((64 * 15 + 1) * 4) + 2] = colorPalette[tempIndex].b //b
      data[j + i * ((64 * 15 + 1) * 4) + 3] = 255 //alfa

    } catch (err) {
      //console.log(err)
    }

  } //for j
} // for i
// put the modified pixels back on the canvas
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript (`for i {` is a syntax error)...

Comment: This wont solve your problem, but you can try to minimize some operations in your  code. For example the try block. (64 * 15 + 1) just have a constant in the top and your Q variables also there are repetitions so define the values ahead.

Comment: My first recommendation is to use a profiler to find out where the time is being spent. But there are obvious improvements to be made. In addition to all the repeated constant expressions that @karthick points out, you have a lot of expressions that can be factored out of the inner loop. For instance, `index_Y` (and every expression that doesn't depend on the current value of `j`) should be evaluated once before the `j` loop starts. Also, for integer expressions, try replacing all those multiplications and divisions by powers of 2 with bit shift operations, which are usually much faster.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I just simplified the code

Comment: @Ted Hopp karthick Thank you I'll try to to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't drawing it onto another canvas do the bilinear interpolation for you?

```
var canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
canvas2.width = canvas2.height = 1024;
ctx2.drawImage( canvas, 0, 0, 1024, 1024 );
```

Comment: Yes, it does but I wanted to implement the interpolation myself. I don't even know what algorithm the upscaling uses (bilinear / bicubic).

Comment: Yeah I don't know either and it would be browser dependent. It is probably done on the GPU which is why it can be so much faster than yours.

Comment: Then I'll try your way. Also can the canvas2 element be created from the same canvas as the low resolution one? Meaning I draw the small picture in canvas1 and the draw the big picture in canvas 2, but both are reference to the same element.

Comment: No you need two elements, you can't draw a canvas onto itself. If it was an image element before which you drew to the first canvas, you could use that directly.

Comment: Works great! Thank you, @Ben West